# Telerik RadControl: Can't find control using suggested method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to solve an annoying problem.
According to Telerik, I should be able to find my control from client-side.

```
var combo = $find(controls.cboDevicesClientID);
console.log("cbo device: " + combo);
```

Where controls is given by my class

```
function init(servicesFramework, controlsSettings, moduleSettings, resourcesSettings, args) {

        sf = servicesFramework;
        controls = controlsSettings;
        settings = moduleSettings;
        resources = resourcesSettings;
        params = args;

        $("input:radio").click(function () {
            setMode($(this).val());
        });
    }
```

In my .ascx, my class is called using this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        mgModule.DmeWizard.init(
            <%= ModuleId %>,
            $.ServicesFramework(<%= ModuleId %>), 
            // Controls
            {
                scopeWrapperId: '<%= ScopeWrapper.ClientID %>',
                cboDevicesClientID: '<%= cboDevices.ClientID %>'
            },
            // Settings
            {
            },
            // Resources
            {
            }
        );
    });
```

My console.log is always null on my device, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that $find() is called after **Sys.Application.Load** because in earlier stages IScriptControls are not initialized and it will return `null`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829.aspx.

Here is an example:

```
            Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
                var combo = $find(controls.cboDevicesClientID);
                console.log("cbo device: " + combo);
            });
```